# How to get text input on Canvas?

Tags: android, input, android-edittext, android-canvas

I'm new in the Android world and I have a very annoying problem. 
In my program I use the Android Canvas. I'd like to add an EditText element, or something like that, to get user text inputs. Can you help me find a way to solve this problem?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: I'm not sure it will answer your question but you can create a `RelativeLayout` and add your canvas and an EditText in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially, you cannot place any edit text or buttonsusig canvas. Instead, you have to draw it. So create a custom layout and draw that layout with canvas

Try this, It might help you. in `onDraw(..)`

```
   LinearLayout lL = new LinearLayout(context);

   EditText editTextView = new EditText(context); 

   editTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   lL.addView(editTextView);

    lL.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    lL.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

    // placing the edit text at specific co-ordinates:
    //canvas.translate(0, 0);
    layout.draw(canvas);
```

And take a look at this another example :  [Click here](http://www.kellbot.com/2009/06/android-hello-circle/)

It gives another way of adding views

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It was very useful for me. But can you tell how can I use the editText's input methods? Should I make listeners for it, or some other way?

Comment: you were you able to insert without using edittext? I am wanting to do the same